# Marble flooring at my house oscillates when we walk over it.How to rectify or resolve this issue?

Tags: flooring, marble

The marble flooring at my house is popping i.e  when people walk over it, the marble flooring oscillates up & down..and it might come out in the next few days if left unattended..kindly provide me a solution as to how to resolve it?.since only 3-4 tiles are having the trouble.

Comment: Not nearly enough detail to give accurate suggestions. Given the information provided I'd say call a flooring guy in to re-set the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several causes for tiles becoming loose. The most popular are:

1). sub-floor not level. An un-even floor won't fully support the tiles. The unsupported area of the tile will slightly flex and overtime will magnify its' motion until it loosens completely.

2). Thin-set not mixed or not properly applied. The cement adhesive needs to be mixed according to the instructions. If there is too much or not enough water the tile will not bond properly. If the thin-set is troweled onto the floor with the wrong sized notched trowel or too thin a layer the tile may not adhere fully.

And 3). the sub-floor must be rigid and secure with no bounce or movement. If it is not prepared correctly by nailing or screwing loose boards down it will flex and transfer that movement through the tile resulting in a failed or loose tile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the tiles up.  You then need to remove the thinset under them and thinset and install the tile.  If you don't have thinset and a good subfloor under you might as well redo the whole room.  If 3-4 tiles are doing this, then it was a very very poor install.  There are a lot of ugly things that can happen with a tile install but this just reeks of the whole job done half-assed.

My personal guess is this job was done with mastic and the mastic has dried and the walking is causing the bond to disengage.